# Confusion regarding sensitivity topic of closed loop system

Tags: control, control-system, terminology

I am reading about closed loop systems in Dorf, *Modern Control Systems.*

While reading, I got confused by highlighted text in the attached snapshot.

What does "variations in parameters" mean. Does it mean changes in the transfer function which is due to changes in poles and zeros locations or addition or removal of poles and/or zeros?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine a vehicle driving at a constant speed along a straight road. The speed is maintained constant by the foot on the accelerator pedal. But, the speed would increase with a tail-wind or decrease with a head-wind. The speed would also decrease if going up a hill and, it would increase if going down the hill.

The wind and the hill are both *variations in the parameters of the process*. So, the control loop (the man driving the car looking at the speedometer and wanting to keep speed constant) would press the pedal harder when going up hill or when there is a head-wind.

It's a manual version of cruise control; it causes the car to use more fuel when travelling up a hill but, keeps the speed constant.

> *Does it mean changes in the transfer function which is due to changes
> in poles and zeros locations or addition or removal of poles and/or
> zeros?*

Yes, it can alter the poles and zeros. Particularly in the example above, a full set of passengers would add more mass to the vehicle and that alters the dynamics which can shift the TF poles.

Answer (score 0):

> What does "variations in parameters" mean?

Example of simple op-amp ... with some "gain".

One can note that if the gain (parameter) of the op-amp is too low, the overall gain of the system is not fixed by the two resistors (20 dB, 40 dB, 60 dB).
One can see that when gain is **higher** then some "value", it does not matter.
So "Overall gain" has a decreased sensitivity versus the "gain" value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of negative feedback is a "decreased sensitivity....to variations in the parameter of the process". In case of analog electronic systems the "process" is very often nothing else than "amplification using a gain stage". That means: Decreased sensitivity to all parameter uncertainties and tolerances which belong to the open-loop gain of the active device.

When - for example - the active device is an opamp, the variations in the open-loop gain Aol play a minor role only and can be neglected (as long as the loop gain caused by the feedback path is suffuiciently larger than unity). This also applies to the input and output impedances of the active device which normally can be neglected during calculation of closed-loop parameters.

In case of a transistor gain stage, it is the sensitivity to the large tolerance of the current gain B (resp. beta) which can be drastically reduced using negative feedback.

As far as poles and zeroes are concerned (important for active filters) the situation is a bit more complex because the sensitivity depends on the selected circuit topology. This is because the location of poles and zeroes is determined by passive lumped elements. In this case, we have to discriminate between (a) active and (b) passive sensitivities.

In some filter topologies (e.g. multi-feedback structure) the active sensitivity (to opamp parameter variations) is more critical (because the opamp is used without internal negative feedback) whereas in some other filter circuits (e.g. Sallen-Key structures) the passive sensitivity (to parts tolerances) dominates because the opamp is used as a finite-gain stage (with internal negative feedback).